# Placing Buttom At Bottom Left Of Screen

Tags: ios, swift

I have this function that creates a button but its not appearing on the screen even though i have added a subview. I also am trying to get it to the bottom left of the screen. I know how to center it but i cant figure out the hole bottom right and bottom left button positioning

```
// will basically crete the login button
lazy var loginButton: UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton(type: .system)
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 114, green: 206, blue: 236, alpha: 0)

    button.setTitle("LOG IN", for: .normal)
    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    button.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: .normal)
    button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 20)

    return button
}()



//will setup constraints for the button
func setupLoginButton(){



}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to give your button a position first.
Something like this:

```
let loginButton: UIButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(100, 400, 100, 50))
```

The CGRectMake function takes these 4 parameters:

```
CGRect(CGFloat x, CGFloat y, CGFloat width, CGFloat height);
```

EDIT

```
 // create button and position it
    let button: UIButton = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(100, 400, 100, 50))

// set all the other properties you did
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 114, green: 206, blue: 236, alpha: 0)

    button.setTitle("LOG IN", for: .normal)
    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    button.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: .normal)
    button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 20)
    // add button to view
    self.view.addSubview(button)
```

EDIT 2

If you want to set the button type, you have to do that first because once the button is created you can't change it nor set the button type:

```
// create button and set button type
let button = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.System)
// position the button
button.frame = CGRect(x: 30, y: 30, width: 150, height: 150)
// set all the other properties you did
button.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 114, green: 206, blue: 236, alpha: 0)

button.setTitle("LOG IN", for: .normal)
button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
button.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: .normal)
button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 20)
// add button to view
self.view.addSubview(button)
```

Comment: wait so do i not need the setupLoginButton function

Comment: and where would i insert the position thing

Comment: Depends, first you have to add a position to your button or else it won't appear. If you like you can add more constraints using your function but it is not required.

Comment: Thanks I was so confused can i add the .system back so it can be clicked

Comment: because now the button is there but i cant click it